# Using a boost::bind result as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost

I have the following code in which I hook callback functions within [ROS](http://www.ros.org) to do the `// Do my stuff` thing in `retSelf()`:

```
template <typename T>
const typename T::ConstPtr retSelf(const typename T::ConstPtr self, size_t id)
{
    // Do my stuff
    return self;
}

template<typename CallbackType, typename ClassType>
void subscribe(void (ClassType::*cb)(typename CallbackType::ConstPtr const),
               ClassType *thisPtr)
{
    auto id = generateId(...);
    auto selfP = &retSelf<CallbackType>;
    auto returnSelf = boost::bind(selfP, _1, id);
    auto callback = boost::bind(cb, thisPtr, returnSelf);

   // Register callback
}
```

Now, this works fine for calls like :

```
void MyClass::MyCallback(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr img){}

subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>(&MyClass::MyCallback, this);
```

However, I have other cases where I want to do something like this:

```
void MyClass::AnotherCallback(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr img, int idx){}

subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>(boost::bind(&MyClass::AnotherCallback, this, _1, 42));
```

That is, I wish to also specify an index parameter that the client software knows about but the template doesn't, and I end up in `AnotherCallback()` with the `42` value set and my code in `retSelf()` executed.

Note I have to use `boost::bind` and not the standard library as ROS only works with the first kind of binding.

Comment: As far as I understand your question you want to pass a `boost::bind`'ed callback to the function. `boost::bind` returns a functional object of type `boost::function<FUNCTION_SIGNATURE>`, where the `FUNCTION_SIGNATURE` in your case should be `void(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr)`. So you can create a method that accepts a `boost::function` as the argument, ex: `void subscribe(const boost::function<void(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr)> &cb);`.

Comment: Ahh, `boost::function` was the bit I was missing - I couldn't find a reference to the return type of `boost::bind`. Can you post that as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::bind` returns the "unspecified-type" functional object, which can be implicitly converted to the `boost::function` with the appropriate template arguments.
So, in your case the return value of `boost::bind(&MyClass::AnotherCallback, this, _1, 42)` can be converted to the `boost::function<void(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr)>`:

```
using callback_t = boost::function<void(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr)>;
void subscribe(const callback_t &callback) {
    // register callback
}

// ...

subscribe(boost::bind(&MyClass::AnotherCallback, this, _1, 42));
```